# ssh not working for Amazon EC2 server

Tags: command-line, ssh, amazon-ec2

I have setup and launched an instance of Amazon EC2 server with Ubuntu in it. Now I have integrated cygwin with command prompt also so all linux commands are working in command prompt.

I tried to access the server using `ssh -i munish.pem ubuntu@52.11.190.155` (munish.pem contains my secret key).

After running this command I get an error: `'ssh' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file`. I searched net and could find solution for github not for Amazon EC2 service...

Comment: cygwin on ubuntu? you sure? :s

Comment: No I am working on windows..By ec2 server is of ubuntu

Comment: Ok, understand now.. have you installed the cygwin ssh package? http://ftp.perforce.com/perforce/tools/benchmarks/browse/doc/cygwin.html

Comment: well I installed all default packages for cygwin..not sure about this.How do I check it?

Comment: Just updated my comment above with a good reference site

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use putty software in window for connecting to the AWS EC2 instance.

Follow the below steps:

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/putty.html

Hope it helps..

Answer (score 0):

You can open PowerShell and check ssh command is available or not.
If not, you can install OpenSSH in Windows 10. See following guide on how to install it.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/openssh/openssh_install_firstuse